# Кнопка удаляющая последнюю написанную цифру в калькуляторе

Tags: java, jtextfield

Помогите написать алгоритм для кнопки калькулятора. Кнопка должна удалять последний(один) написанный элемент. 
Например:

Почему таким образом не удаляется последний элемент?

```
        String str;
        JTextField t1;
        str = t1.getText();
        t1.setText(null);
        t1.setText(t1.setText() + (str.length() - 1));
```

А вот так без всякой проблемы можно удалить последний символ:
Почему нельзя сделать это без substring()?

```
    String str;
    JTextField t1;
    str = t1.getText();
    t1.setText(null);
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    t1.setText(t1.getText() + str);
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества вопросы не должны сводиться к завершению задач за учащихся. Приведите пример вашей реализации и задайте вопрос с описанием конкретных проблем.

Comment: Вы просмотрите еще раз свой код и подумайте что Вы делаете каждым шагом: `t1.setText(null);` - присваиваете текстовому полю пустоту, хотя это не правильно, чтобы очистить поле надо делать `t1.setText("");`. Затем `t1.setText(t1.setText() + (str.length() - 1));` - вы непонятно зачем берете `t1.setText()`: устанавливаете в поле "ничего" и к нему складываете, не присоединяете, длину строки `str` минус 1. Будет краш на краше. Текстовое поле принимает тип `string`. Метод `substring();` возвращает строку от указанного начально символа, до указанного конечного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str = "string";
void modString(){
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Выведет: `strin`